# Clustered @schedule annotations in Spring

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

My codebase currently uses a crontab-like `quartz.properties` file to define a series of jobs in our Spring web app. Our quartz config currently looks like:

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId=AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.jmx.export=true

org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=20

org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold=6000000
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=dataSourceConnectionProvider
```

I've recently become enamored of Spring's `@scheduled` annotation and would really like to take advantage of it. There are plenty of instances where we have some job bean that essentially wraps a single method of a service -- the annotations seem like they'd remove a lot of boilerplate and more our code more legible as a result.

However, I can't figure out how I could get the same guarantees from Spring's scheduling that we do from vanilla quartz right now. That is, setting `isClustered=true` and the job store implementation to use a backing database enables us to guarantee that our jobs run once per cluster without doing something unpleasant like declaring a master node and checking hostnames -- which isn't even a good guarantee for us, since we have a variable number of nodes. Nonetheless, it seems like it should be possible -- Spring's scheduling is obviously very aware of Quartz, and I have to imagine that there's a way to implement a `TaskScheduler` that would provide these guarantees.